# Cula routine sgbtrf undefined

Tags: cula

When I try to call the CULA routine `GBTRF` I get this error identifier "culaSgbtrf" is undefined, but everything else (inizializaion, GetErrorInfoStrin etc ..,)  seems to work fine. Does anybody know why and can help me?

Comment: The free edition does not contain this function.  See [here](http://www.culatools.com/cula_dense_programmers_guide/).  Maybe you have the wrong edition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me how can I check my edition? (The reason is that I didn't install cula by myself, they only give me this machine on which i'm supposed to work!). Thank you again.